# MVC Placeholder in Dropdownlist

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

How can I put a placeholder in a dropdownlist? I already had to search, but I still could not find the solution.

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrap-input100 rs1-wrap-input100 validate-input">
     <span class="label-input100">Room</span>
     @Html.DropDownList("ID_Room", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "focus-input100" })
     <span class="focus-input100"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: by placeholder you mean a default item like "-- please select --" or something, at the top of the list? If so then see JamesS' answer below (and also the MVC documentation for the DropdownList helper, where you can see that overload of the method which accepts this extra parameter to set the default option) If you're thinking of the "placeholder" attribute which puts a little hint in faint writing into a field (which disappears when you start to enter a value), you can't use that here - it's only valid on `<input` or `<textarea` elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 @Html.DropDownList("ID_Room", null, "placeholder" , new { @class = "focus-input100" })
```

Also. you don't need to `htmlAttributes`. Just having `new {}` is fine